# WPF: EF to ObservableCollection and DataGrid auto-update: a definitive solution

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, wpfdatagrid, observablecollection, auto-update

I am relatively new to WPF and the MVVM model, but after hours of searching and reading articles regarding the matter, I have not come up with a definitive solution to this.

1) Model: I have an EF model relying on an SQL Express database. For this example, I will use a property named Visits, a DbSet(Of Visit).

2) ViewModel: an ObservableCollection(Of Visit). It is declared as such:

```
Private _Visits As ObservableCollection(Of Visit)
Public Property Visits As ObservableCollection(Of Visit)
    Get
        Return _Visits
    End Get
    Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of Visit))
        _Visits = value
        RaisePropertyChanged("Visits")
    End Set
End Property
...
Visits = New ObservableCollection(Of Visit)(
    From V In Application.context.Visits
    Where V.IsRobotGenerated AndAlso
    Not V.IsSynced
)
```

3) View: a WPF datagrid.

```
<DataGrid
    x:Name="grdVisits"
    ItemsSource="{
        Binding Path=Visits,
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}
    }"
/>
```

Now I have a background thread which modifies the EF data directly (does all CRUD operations).
What I want is the datagrid to reflect these changes as they happen.

What I am doing right now is replace the Visits ObservableCollection by re-calling the constructor above, which results to 2 drawbacks:

1) Performance wise I suppose it is not the best choice, especially when we are talking about quite a few thousands of rows (each with its RowDetails).

2) The user has in the meantime scrolled down the datagrid or opened a RowDetailsTemplate. His position and everything is lost if the entire collection is reset.

I have read somewhere about DependencyProperties but I do not have time to go through it thoroughly since I have no clue if it is a pointer to the right direction. If it is, I will be happy to do so.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add or remove elements from an `ObservableCollection` bound to an `ItemsSource`, those changes are instantly reflected so what you need to do is simply to modify the `ObservableCollection` accordingly as your CRUD operations take place.

Bear in mind that if you are using a version of .NET prior to 4.5 you'll need to dispatch the `ObservableCollection` changes to the UI thread.

**UPDATE**: answering to the comment

> What about the following scenario: two datagrids in the view, which are bound to two different ObservableCollections. However, these ObservableCollections are created with a different constructor so as to apply filtering to the underlying Visits. Can you provide a bare bones example as to how I can accomplish the aforementioned?

Filtering is a different story. It is supported by an intermediate layer set between your collection and the items control (`ObservableCollection` and `DataGrid` respectively in this case): collection views. Actually, [you always bind to collection views, not to the collections directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6317975/3042204).

So, for your scenario you'd bind both `DataGrids` to the same underlying collection but using two different collection views, one for each `DataGrid`. This way, the data stays the same and synchronized with whatever you need it to be (your CRUD operations for instance). However, each `DataGrid` can display a subset of the data based on filtering, sorted and/or grouped in a different way.

I'd suggest you take a look into the [MSDN article regarding data binding to collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms752347.aspx#binding_to_collections).

Comment: So as far as I understand, my CRUD thread must talk with the ViewModel which will in turn update the Model, not the Model itself.

Comment: What about the following scenario: two datagrids in the view, which are bound to two different ObservableCollections. However, these ObservableCollections are created with a different constructor so as to apply filtering to the underlying Visits. Can you provide a bare bones example as to how I can accomplish the aforementioned?

Comment: Well, that depends on the complexity of your implementation. You could actually use commands that fire the CRUD operations and events that notify of their success and modify the `ObservableCollection`; even doing so with a service layer. What I find important regarding your question is that you realize that what you need to keep your `DataGrid` synchronized is reflect changes by modifying its bound `ObservableCollection`, not re-creating it.

Comment: @GeorgeGkionis I've updated the answer to answer the question in your comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I suppose I need major refactoring to adhere to this schema.