# Reset DataGrid Sorting back to its initial state

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have created a view that contains some buttons and a DataGrid. The DataGrid displays items as the application parses an excel file. I have added a button that cancels the parsing thread. I am able to clear the DataGrid the only issue I am having is if any of the columns have been sorted that sort persists through the cancel.

Heres an example of my Datagrid:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Parts}"
                  Visibility="{Binding DatagridIsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityInverseParameterConverter}}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  Margin="0,0,0,44" 
                  FontSize="20" 
                  AlternationCount="2"
                  AlternatingRowBackground="WhiteSmoke"
                  CanUserAddRows="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns >
    <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Raw Data" 
                         Binding="{Binding RawData}">
        <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="Border.BorderThickness" Value="0 0 1 0"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>   
    <DataGridTextColumn  Header="Manufacturer" Binding="{Binding Manu}">
        <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                <Setter Property="Border.BorderThickness" Value="0 0 1 0"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>       
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I have combed through the internet and have found examples on how to do this using the code behind method but I am really trying to stick to MVVM for this.

Is this even possible?

Comment: What is the class of Parts (ItemsSource) ?

Comment: Parts is a property for an ObservableCollection of a Type I made that just contains Strings

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should use a **Collection View instead of an Observable Collection for your ItemsSource**, because if you use an Observable Collection you only have a Collection View so all changes are kept. However if you use a Collection View you can change the collection view and remove the sorting.

You can [see more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317860/should-i-bind-to-icollectionview-or-observablecollection)

I hope that this can help you

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer I seem to have gotten the sort to clear but the arrow that displays if the sort is ascending or descending is left behind.